# Can you create asymmetrical encryption algorithm from symmetrical, without knowing how the algorithm works?

Tags: encryption, implementation

Let's imagine that we have some symmetrical encryption algorithm, that has only two functions: `Encrypt(Data, Key)` and `Decrypt(Data, Key)`. Let's say that the algorithm is strong and quick, but we don't know how it works. Is it possible only using those two functions to create a usable asymmetrical encryption algorithm? If not, is there any way to add anything that will help us create one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not known whether it is possible to construct secure public-key encryption schemes from private-key ones (and by extension, from one-way functions). From [Barak's recent survey](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/365):

> One could ask if there really is an inherent difference between public-key and private-key cryptography or maybe this is simply a reflection of our ignorance.  That is, is it is not possible to build a public-key cryptosystem out  of an arbitrary one-way function and hence base it on the same assumptions as private-key encryption? The answer is that we do not know

In fact, this is one of the most important open questions in cryptography, along with the question of whether one-way functions exist. So, in practice you can consider that it is not possible, and consult the above for a survey of the known methods to construct public-key cryptosystems.

See also [Impagliazzo's "Five Worlds"](https://www.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~krajicek/ri5svetu.pdf); your question can be reworded as: is it possible that we live in Minicrypt, the world where one-way functions exist but public-key cryptography does not?

Comment: We can build signature schemes out of arbitrary one-way functions.

Comment: @forest It could be argued that signature schemes are related to public-key cryptosystems only in a superficial way, and that they fundamentally belong to private-key cryptography, precisely because they can be constructed from OWFs.